# Tell vim to write to file when contents of buffer change

Tags: vim

I'd like for vim to save the current buffer to a file each time the buffer is changed. I don't want it to leave Insert mode if I'm typing away. Just do it quietly in the background and don't bother me. It's like a zealous auto save.

Sending the new contents to an external process would work, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a timer, auto save after you leave for 30 seconds.

```
set updatetime=30000
au CursorHold * :w
```

**note:** this event is only triggered in Normal mode.

Comment: you can change `30000` to `3000`

Comment: it looks like it's trigger in insert mode, too

Comment: `:help CursorHold` says it works only in normal mode. The `CursorHoldI` autocommand is for _INSERT_ mode. `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI` may be helpful too. Assuming this is related to your "Cloud Vim" project you may need to set `updatetime` to a small value, I think.